# How to use ignite data streamer with binary objects, data not loaded to cluster

Tags: java, ignite

I have a server cache based on Java Pojo.

```java
IgniteCache<Long, Asset> assets
```

with config

```java
 CacheConfiguration<Long, Asset> CACHE = new CacheConfiguration()
    .setName(Asset.NAME)
        .setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED)
        .setBackups(0)
        .setStoreKeepBinary(true)
        .setIndexedTypes(Long.class, Asset.class);
  }
```

I would like to load data using a client-side streamer using BinaryObjects so I don't have a dependency on the Pojo -> Asset

There are no exceptions on the client-side but I don't see any data created on the cluster

```java
    final IgniteDataStreamer<Long, BinaryObject> streamer = ignite.dataStreamer("Asset");
    streamer.perNodeBufferSize(10);
    streamer.allowOverwrite(false);
    streamer.keepBinary();

      long id = faker.random().nextLong(1000);
      BinaryObjectBuilder builder = binary.builder("Asset");

      builder.setField("id", id, Long.TYPE);
      builder.setField("name", "John Doe", String.class);
      builder.setField("timezone", TimeZone.getDefault(), TimeZone.class);
      final BinaryObject build = builder.build();
      streamer.addData(id, build);
```

No data is loaded to the cache.

is there a mismatch between the pojo and the binary object?

what am I doing wrong?

Note: Streaming with the real Asset object works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [flush()](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteDataStreamer.html#flush--) the streamer. This would force it to send the queued data to the server. Worked in my reproducer.

Alternatively, put more entries into the stream  than the [buffer size](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteDataStreamer.html#perNodeBufferSize-int-)

You can also set the [auto flush frequency](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteDataStreamer.html#autoFlushFrequency-long-), forcing the streamer to flush on a set interval.

Comment: interesting, my buffer size was 10 and still nothing was added. once I added this     streamer.autoFlushFrequency(1000); I am getting the Assets.

Comment: please add the auto flush to your answer and I will accept it.